# How to exit all entrees when profit is reached?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to figure out how to exit all open positions when using pyramiding with take profit. But when the profit target is hit each entry is closed individually instead of as a whole. Here is my code:

```
if ta.crossover(close,close[1])
strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
strategy.exit("Take profit", "Long", profit = 500)
```

Answer (score 0):

Each trade/entry has a unique id therefore they are being closed individually.

Comment: How do I group them all together so that they are all closed at the same time?